# XCode Error : target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I've recently got my hands on a old Xcode Project ( sdk was set to iOS 2.2 )
but when I try to compile it it gives me this error :

```
target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework', but there's no such      product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform
```

And "iphonesimulator" changes to Device if I set my iPhone as build target.
Ofcource i've looked for solutions before i asked, but none worked. 
( Remove .pbxuser in the XcodeProject map )

I can't find any references to com.apple.product-type.framework in the project whatsoever.

I've used Xcode 3.0, 3.2.6, 4.2, But none of these versions make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated :)